# Algorithms for projecting a point onto the convex hull spanned by a set of vectors

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls, barycentric-coordinates

Given a set of vectors $V = \{ \mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_n \} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, I want to project a point $\mathbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ onto the convex hull $\text{conv}(V)$ of the vectors in $V$.

I know this is a quadratic program, to find $\mathbf{z}^*$ that minimizes $\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{x}_0 - \mathbf{z}\|^2$ subject to $\mathbf{z} \in \text{conv}(V)$.

I also know that $\text{conv}(V)$ is a polytope and expressible as a set $S = \{ \mathbf{x} : A\mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{b} \}$.

However, I don't know how to derive the constraint matrix and constraint vector $(A,\mathbf{b})$ from the vectors in $V$.

Secondarily, I'm wondering if there are simple and fast algorithms to solve this problem. The number of vectors in $V$ will be less than $250$ and the dimensionality will be less than $50$.

And finally, I am hoping to express the solution $\mathbf{z}^* = \text{Proj}(\mathbf{x}_0)$ in something like barycentric coordinates with respect to the vectors in $V$. In other words, I'd like to express $\mathbf{z}^*$ as the vector $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ such that $\mathbf{z}^* = \sum_i \alpha_i \mathbf{v}_i$ with $\alpha_i \ge 0$ and $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1$. Given that the set $V$ won't be linearly independent (because $n > d$), I know that such barycentric coordinates are not well defined. I'm hoping to use something akin to a least norm solution $\|\alpha\|^2$ here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to express the convex hull explicitly as a system of inequalities $\mathbf{A x} \leq \mathbf{b}$. The convex hull, by definition, is 
$$
\operatorname{conv}(\mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_m) = \left \{
 \sum_{i=1}^m w_i \mathbf{v}_i : \sum_{i=1}^m w_i=1, w_i \geq 0
\right\}
$$

Therefore, the projection onto the convex hull of a vector $\mathbf{y}$ can be computed from the solution of
$$
\min_{\mathbf{w}} \quad \left \|  \sum_{i=1}^m w_i \mathbf{v}_i - \mathbf{y} \right \|_2^2 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \sum_{i=1}^m w_i=1, w_i \geq 0
$$
The vector $\mathbf{w}$ contains the barycentric coordinates of the projection. I am not aware of a specialized algorithm of computing the optimal $\mathbf{w}$, but any QP solver can do so.

A simple solution method which you can implement yourself can be obtained from a fast projected gradient algorithm ,such as [FISTA](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/080716542), and remembering that the constraints are exactly the unit simplex, and there is a simple $O(m \log m)$ algorithm for projecting a point onto the unit simplex. Moreover, you also have the well-known Mirror Descent algorithm for optimizing over the unit simplex, which can be quite fast in practice.

Comment: $+1$ for an elegant answer .. I think the optimal way would be a brute-force of order $O(N^m)$ where $N$ would be the size of the grid, or more generally $O(\prod_{k=1}^m N_k)$ if each $w_k$ is searched on a different grid of size $N_k$.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi, what grid are you referring to? A grid defined on $[0,1]^m$? I believe that this becomes impractical even for a small value of $m$, say, $m \geq 5$.

Comment: True .. that is the optimal and yet an impractical solution.

Comment: @AlexShtof - what's a good reference on mirror descent?

Comment: This one: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~xzhang/teaching/bregman.pdf

Comment: Using the OP's original notation, it might help to write the problem more compactly as $$\min_{w  \in \Delta_n} \|Vw-x_0\|_2^2,$$  where $\Delta_n$ is the $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex and $V$ is the $d$ by $n$ matrix with $j$th column $v_j$. Also, there are in fact $\mathcal O(n)$ algorithms for projection onto $\Delta_n$.